Turning image into polygonal mesh
I don't seem to be able to find a mac OS software which takes as input an image, like the one below and outputs another image consisting of a polygonal/triangular mesh approximating the input image. Ideally I would be able to control the number of triangles generated in the mesh (I'm hoping for 20-40 in this example).
Does anybody know of such a tool?


Looks like this is a photo of a piece of partially transparent ribbon which contains parallel fibers.  It can also be a rendered 3D model of such item. Do you want a 2D image or a 3D model? You should present a mesh and original image pair which reveals the conversion to mesh idea that you expect. Converting this to a low poly 2D image either in Photoshop or by using website https://stonet2000.github.io/Polytomizator/ is simple. But it's a manual job and you'll get something like this https://i.sstatic.net/f5YOssw6.png I guess you want something finer. What is it?

hey thanks a lot @user8922027 for your comment. This website is cool. I guess what it's lacking a bit is an understanding of the topology of my image, by which I mean how the painted "ribbon" lies in space. Do you know how to achieve this? If it was 3D that would be great but even 2D works.
And I'ld love to attach a mesh of what I have in mind but I don't know how to draw it :)

The illusion of the way how it lies in the space is created very much by the wavy fine fibers. A rough polygon mesh cannot carry that information. A 2D image of geometrically right 3D polygon mesh (it's NOT a low poly version of a 2D image, no matter the 2D image might present a 3D ribbon)!!!!)  may well look right  without the fibers. The 3D mesh must be built in a 3D program, Ordinary graphic software cannot cannot convert your photo to it. Artificial intelligence might be able to do it if it has seen it done somewhere.

Understood, thanks @user8922027. What about if it was painted all solid, like the leftmost portion of the ribbon - I'm not so eager to capture the fibers in the mesh; even if it was all solid, as long as the mesh respects how the ribbon lies in space. Would that make things easier?

This one https://i.sstatic.net/lGmwK5k9.png is a rendered low resolution 3D triangle mesh model of a solid random  ribbon which has been bent and twisted. (it's not yours, it's what I happened to create by making a few quick movements in a 3D program)

very nice! That's exactly what I'm looking for - thanks for sharing. Are you using blender or which program are you using?

I am just trying Rhinoceros. This is a triangle mesh export from there and opened again to see the triangles. Originally it was a smooth planar curve which was extruded to a bent ribbon, The bent ribbon was twisted along a straight line. The colors of the sides of the surface are a remnant from the previous messing with the program.

I don't think there is any software which can do this automatically if that is what you are asking.  I think you would need to make it manually using some 3D software, such as Blender. There's a Blender stack exchange if you get stuck.
